# Retrieve Stored Procedures

Tags: php, procedures, sqlsrv

Below I am trying to call a stored procedure with the following four parameters. However, I am not getting any errors, and the result is not producing any records. I ran the query in the DB which populates 1 record. Any ideas?

```
<?php
//// GET CONNECTIONS
include('../Connect/con.php'); 
if(!$conn){
    echo 'Connection failed.';    
}

if ($conn){

    $sql = "{call up_lkpAddressSearch} @State=N'FL', @county=N'BROWARD', @HouseNbr=N'3117', @StreetName=N'COCOPLUM'";
    $query_address = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

    if( $query_address === false )
    {
         echo "Error in statement preparation/execution.\n";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    if( $query_address === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    /* Make the first row of the result set available for reading. */
    if( sqlsrv_fetch( $query_address ) === false )
    {
         echo "Error in retrieving row.\n";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }   


    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query_address, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            $id = $row['SA_PROPERTY_ID'];
            echo $id;
    }
} 
// END CONNECTION TEST
sqlsrv_close( $query_address );
?>
```

I continued to try and produce a record, and I am able to echo out

```
$id = sqlsrv_get_field( $query_addressSearch, 0);
echo $id .'<br />';
```

However, the while loop is not producing a record.

Regards
Josh

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too.  You have to use the sqlsrv question mark convention. Here is a good link for using named parameters with sqlsrv.

[calling stored procedure with named parameters](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0ea1dc2-b28b-4ef4-a386-f69b154b39ef/calling-stored-procedure-with-named-parameters-sqlsrvquery-php-iis7)